# How to stop Google's Play Store from auto-updating itself (without rooting)?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I have a problem with my tab. With the new version of Play Store, My tablet PC keeps restarting. So, I restored Google Play to the Factory Default. Soon after, it updated itself, causing the device to restart repeatedly when in standby. I am running 4.1.1 on my Karbonn ST10. I, at the time of posting the question, do not have any intention to root the tab.

Thanks,
Oxylibrium.

Comment: Instead of trying to stop Google Play from updating, maybe you should try stopping your tablet from restarting or get it replaced if it's under warranty. Since it's not rooted, you should be under warranty..?

Comment: If I try to give it for service, they say "We no longer support this device." Hope that explains it.

Comment: I also found these four possible methods of preventing the Play Store from updating itself. I haven't tried any of these methods myself, though. http://skyblue2779.blogspot.nl/2012/03/how-to-disable-auto-update-for-android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Setting--> Data Usage

under the usage graph there is list of apps with usage specified on right side.

Go to Google Play and at the below you will find Option ***Restrict  Background Data***
click on that check box..

and here you go.

Though you cant install any apps from Play store with these setting, but you can always enable background data whenever needed.

Comment: Thanks, but this option is not available in my tab's settings.

Comment: This is no longer a valid solution as Google Play enables background data itself if it detects they are disabled

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple solution for Android 7 (1GB/8GB (sys 4 + usr 4)) system.
Wifi started to clog and some apps to misbehave because of shortage of RAM and/or RAM cache.
The user storage free space was only 100 MB.

1. Disable apps autoupdate in Play Store.
2. Uninstall updates for Google App and Google Play Store.
3. In the new (old) Google Play Store disable apps autoupdate again.
4. If Play Store/Google App starts to update itself cancel it.
5. Find or record a "dummy" video of about 50 MB
6. Copy that video to user storage as many times as needed to leave about 200 MB free space.
7. Android cleans about 100 MB of user storage to enable at least one of the bloated apps to autoupdate.
8. Cancel the autoupdate if needed and fill the extra space with 2 additional copies of your dummy video.
9. Free space is now about 200 MB again, but there is no room for cleaning anything any more.
10. Android gives up and your phone works fine. There is much more free RAM because the Google App and Google Play Store are the factory versions (with some "missing" features, of course). There is enough RAM cache because user storage free space is about 200 MB (hold it on that level by adding/removing copies of your dummy video if needed).

Answer (score -2):

Your phone must be rooted to try the following steps:

1. Go to `data/app/`.
2. Enter the command `chattr +i /data/app/com.android.vending-1.apk` (this is partial info and you need to Google for more) .

Comment: I could've considered it a partial answer but I cannot because there is virtually no reason mentioned or the amount of success achieved. It's simply of no use as it's is currently written. Consider explaining what you're trying to do, and try to post when you've completed the job.

Comment: Also `chattr +i /data/app/com.android.vending-1.apk` changes the attribute of that APK file, making it immune from any future changes. It doesn't create an APK!